# How to hide all instances of the Desktop?

Tags: unity, nautilus

I don't use the concept of a Desktop. How can I hide all instances of the Desktop shown in the images below?

**Nautilus:**

[image]

**Open File Dialogue:**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can not. Just ignore the entry. You can lock the Desktop folder in your home folder to get an error every time you try to save something there. But I am not sure what problems it can bring later.

```
chmod a-w ~/Desktop
```